# Character level CNN - 1D or 2D

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, nlp, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I want to implement a character-level CNN in Pytorch.

My input has **4** dimensions:

> *(batch_size, seq_length, padded_character_length, embedding_dim)*

I'm wondering whether I should merge two dimensions and use a `Conv1D`-layer or instead use a `Conv2D`-layer on the existing dimensions.

Given the dimensions of the input both would *technically* work fine, I also have seen implementations for both versions. So I'm wondering which method to prefer.

Does one of the two methods have particular advantages over the other?

Comment: I'm wondering `padded_character_length` is for padding character in word level? Let's say it = 4:  `name -> [n, a, m, e]`, `is -> [i, s, 0, 0]`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @DavidNg Yes, every word is padded or truncated to a fixed number of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Venkatesh that 1D might make more sense for your implementation. Instead of merging, I typically use the [TimeDistributed](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/#timedistributed) layers that are found in Keras. This takes one layer and applies it across time dimensions. The advantage is that you keep the features from each dimension separate until you want to merge them.

If you are using padding (as you mentioned) then it makes more sense to apply the same layer across the time dimensions instead of merging the layers and creating awkward padding space in between actual characters. TimeDistributed layers solves this.

I googled for just a moment and found someone who has tried implementing this feature in PyTorch, that might at least get you started.

[PyTorch TimeDistributed](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/any-pytorch-function-can-work-as-keras-timedistributed/1346/4)

**To expand on my usage a bit..** My latest model has 5, 12 hour periods, each 12 hour period has sporadic activity so it is padded to reach a standard length of 30, so the final input shape is (?, 5, 30, embedding_size). I generate features *within* a single period using a TimeDistributed 1D CNN, then I max pool those features and concatenate to create a new shape of (?, 5, n_feats) where there are now 5 sets of feature maps. I again run that data over with a different 1D CNN layer which looks *across* the 5, 12 hour periods. The padding in each period is independent of each other, so I can't simply use a 2D CNN as elements at the same index wouldn't represent the same time across periods.

**Edit:**

I think the Keras implementation is a little more sophisticated but that should be close. Their documentation says "This wrapper applies a layer to every temporal slice of an input." If getting there requires to merge then restore after then their may be some considerations around the feature map. For example, if the filter size is 2 then the last item in the first feature map (after reshaping) will include the last feature and the first feature between two time slices.

Here is [one more link](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1927) on discussion around this capability in PyTorch that might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think I will try it this way. Looking at that PyTorch implementation it seems that it basically merges / flattens two dimensions, forwards the reshaped input into a module and restores the dimensions afterwards. Or is there anything else TimeDistributed usually does?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing like which is best out of Conv1D and Conv2D.

Generally Conv1D is used on text data and Conv2D is used on image data.

Considering that you'll be implementing character level CNN, it makes more sense to use Conv1D.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to come back here as I have tried both variants, using **Conv2D** *and* **Conv1D** with *TimeDistributed*.
After a several experiments, I'll stay with a **Conv2D** layer, as this leads to significantly better results for my setup.

I guess the results really depend on the specific implementation, however I cannot support the statement that **Conv1D** layers are generally better suited for character level CNNs.

*So **Conv2D** layers are definitely worth considering for this application!*

Comment: Would you explain more in details which kernel size, and number of kernels for `Conv2D` in this example? Thanks!

Comment: I used a version similar to what you can find [here under `Embedding`](https://github.com/BangLiu/QANet-PyTorch/blob/master/model/QANet.py#L181). Kernel size is (1, 5), so the kernel is pretty much moving like a 1D convolution except the fact that it processes an additional dimension without any flattening.

Comment: thanks for your code reference. It is worth reading how the modules are combined together into `Embedding` :)